# How to get the latest post in Laravel? Only the latest

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to pull the latest task to then set that progress after the latest is deleted to keep the progress updated.

So, Imagine I have 20% of the task solved first, I add a progress which adds 30% and then, I got 50%. But, somehow I noticed that the progress made is not correct and I have to delete it, so, the progress has to go back to 20%

A bit more visual:

20% + 30% = 50%

50% - 30% = 20%

Being that said, In my controller I have the following:

```
public function destroy(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $id = Progress::where('id', $id)->first();
        $task = $id->task;
        $id->delete();
        $progress = $task->progresses->(dont know how to get the latest one ???);
        $task->progress = $progress->progress; /* we set the latest progress to be the current one */
        $task->update();
        $task->save();
        return response()->json([
        "code" => 200,
        "message" => "Progress deleted successfully"
        ]);
    }
```

How can I get the latest one to set it as the current?

Comment: I assume `$task->progress` is a number? If so the way you are currently doing it would be wrong, no? What if this task has 3 progresses, now you delete one, you cannot just get the latest one and update the task, since you would need the combined progress from the two remaining progresses? you would need to sum up all progresses and then save that into `$task->progress`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$task->progresses->last()`

Answer (score 6):

latest() is a function defined in Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder Class.

```
$id = Progress::where('id', $id)->latest()->first(); //to get just the most recent created at.
```

By default it takes the created at column in it. You can set it for updated_at by using `->latest('updated_at')` .
t will just orderBy with the column you provide in descending order and take the last value.

Comment: This solution should be used instead of accepted answer because in accepted answer there is fetch of all collection's items first then selecting last item. This answer just grab latest item from DB and is acceptable faster and better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your this query

```
$id = Progress::where('id', $id)->first();
```

to this to fetch the latest record

```
$id = Progress::where('id', $id)->latest('created_at')->get()->first();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you pass the condition using where clause, then it wil return that row only which mathches the id. So remove that where clause condition.

Simply call the latest() method.

```
$id = Progress::latest()->first();
```

instead of

```
$id = Progress::where('id', $id)->first();
```

This will return the latest row.

Note that, in the latest() method used created_at column to find the latest row. You may pass the column name if it is other than created_at column.

```
$id = Progress::latest('created_at')->first();
```